# Why is my PDFRenderer so small?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, internal-storage, pdfrenderer

I have a workking PDF downloader and PDFRenderer. I am using openFileInput method to keep the file secure from scanners. My problem is the Bitmap generated is so small it cannot be read. I tried to use  like every example recommended but I cannot get it to load the APK too many logcats to list. There are none with this version. Device is Galaxy S6 I only have AMD computers so no emulators here and **NO SDCard recommendations for security reasons I am using APP Specific storage**

Screenshot of PDFRenderer Bitmap:

[image]

XML code:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="net.madjobber.pdfdemo.PDFRender">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="371dp"
    android:layout_height="437dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="previous"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/next"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Downloader Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    String fileDownloadPath = "https://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/GRE/pdf/gre_research_validity_data.pdf";
    String saveFilePath = "";

ProgressDialog dialog = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","File is Being Downloaded",true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    downloadFile(fileDownloadPath,saveFilePath);
                }

            }).start();

        }
    });
}
public void downloadFile(String fileDownloadPath,String saveFilePath)

{

    try {

        URL u = new URL(fileDownloadPath);
        URLConnection con = u.openConnection();
        int lengthofContent=con.getContentLength();
        DataInputStream DIStream=new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
        byte[] buffer=new byte[lengthofContent];
        DIStream.readFully(buffer);
        DIStream.close();

        DataOutputStream DOStream=new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + "PDF.pdf"));
        DOStream.write(buffer);
        DOStream.flush();
        DOStream.close();

        hideProgressIndicator();


    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        hideProgressIndicator();



    }
    catch (IOException e) {


    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }

}

private void hideProgressIndicator() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
public void PDFRenderer (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PDFRender.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

}
```

PDFRenderer JAVA:

```
public class PDFRender extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView imageView;
private int currentPage = 0;
private Button next,previous;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdfrender);


    next =(Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentPage++;
            render();

        }
    });
    previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentPage--;
            render();

        }
    });
    render();
}
private void render() {
    //open PDF from internal storage and pass the variable to renderer
    String Path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath();

    File file = new File( Path +"/PDF.pdf");
    try{


        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        int REQ_WIDTH = imageView.getWidth();
        int REQ_HEIGHT = imageView.getHeight();


        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(REQ_WIDTH, REQ_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

        if (currentPage < 0){
            currentPage = 0;
        }else if (currentPage > renderer.getPageCount()) {
            currentPage = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;
        }
        Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
        Rect rect =new Rect(0, 0, REQ_WIDTH, REQ_HEIGHT);
        renderer.openPage(currentPage).render(bitmap, rect, m, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imageView.invalidate();


    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





}
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated as even with cheater glasses I cannot read the PDF. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Remove fix height and width of image.

Comment: I got it Thanks though

Comment: replaced rect and m in line:-renderer.openPage(currentPage).render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY); and eliminated Matrix and Rect lines